# Using pre-assigned column name within a pipe

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to pre-assign my column name and use that within a dplyr pipe

Here's an example. I want to do this:

```
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(Var = mean(Petal.Length[Sepal.Width > 3]))
```

But with the column name assigned outside of the pipe, like this

```
col_name <- "Petal.Length"

iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(Var = mean(!!col_name[Sepal.Width > 3]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert to symbol (`sym`) and then do the evaluation (`!!`)

```
iris %>%
 group_by(Species) %>%   
 summarise(Var = mean((!!rlang::sym(col_name))[Sepal.Width >3]))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  Species      Var
#  <fct>      <dbl>
#1 setosa      1.48
#2 versicolor  4.65
#3 virginica   5.72
```

---

If we need to use only `dplyr`, then can pass the variable object in `summarise_at`

```
iris %>%
   group_by(Species) %>% 
   summarise_at(vars(col_name), funs(mean(.[Sepal.Width > 3])))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  Species    Petal.Length
#  <fct>             <dbl>
#1 setosa             1.48
#2 versicolor         4.65
#3 virginica          5.72
```

Comment: It's not possible with core tidyverse functions?

Comment: @Shinobi_Atobe `rlang` is also included in tidyverse

Comment: If we really wanted to use only `dplyr`, then use the `summarise_at` i.e. `iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise_at(vars(col_name), funs(mean(.[Sepal.Width > 3])))`